# Raphael.js analytics - is it poss to show 2 charts on same page displayed vertically?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, raphael, analytics

Is it possible to show 2 Raphael.js analytics charts with different data on the same page? Also is it possible to show the charts **vertically** instead of horizontally?

If anyone can point me to an example or tutorial that would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can create two different panels in extjs and insert in each a raphael.js analysis. And two panels will share the screen of course ;)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply - I've moved away from raphael for the time being as I've got what i wanted via html5 canvas. However i will be coming back to raphael as it is so cool and flexible. Thanks